# Python multiline regex on large file without buffering whole file

Tags: python, regex, large-files

What would be the fastest way in Python to do a multiline regex search over a large file?

I commonly see:

1. using `for line in file`. This does not work for multiline regexs
2. buffering the whole file, e.g. `text = file.read()`. This does not scale to very large files

I'm looking for some way to stream data from a file directly to a compiled regex.

Exact usecase:
I'm trying to find all TC values and the names of the signal (last level only is fine, don't need the full hierarchical name) in a saif file. The pattern I'm looking for is for instance

```
(signalname\[14\]
  (T0 5519100) (T1 12540900) (TX 0)
  (TC 5) (IG 0)
)
```

The whitespace is as far as I know, interchangeable with any whitespace.
The pattern is enclosed within other blocks, which I do not further care about.
I specifically care about the TC value and the name (with optional index).
A regex that seems to work with for instance `pcregrep -M` is `\(\s*([0-9a-zA-Z_]*(?:\\\[[0-9]+\\\])?)\s*\(\s*T0\s*[0-9]+\s*\)\s*\(\s*T1\s*[0-9]+\s*\)\s*\(\s*TX\s*[0-9]+\s*\)\s*\(\s*TC\s*([0-9]+)\s*\)\s*\(\s*IG\s*[0-9]+\s*\)\s*\)`. Looking at `pcregrep`'s memory usage, it seems to run in a streaming-approach and thus do what I want. I'm looking for a python way to do this.

Comment: I indeed assumed a wrong meaning of MULTILINE. It is not necessary. There might be a better tool than regexes, yes. Could you clarify?

Comment: It all depends on what you intend to do.

Comment: I have a large file with a pattern that occurs often (but the file contains other things as well), I want to extract each occurence from the file or, more precisely, a specific number following a keyword in the pattern. But the pattern itself is defined by more than keyword+number and the whitespaces in the pattern can contain newlines.

Comment: All depends on the type of file and the expected matches structure (the pattern itself may tell you how to work it around).

Comment: @KoenG. This was closed as a duplicate because there are other questions which discuss the problem of running arbitrary regexes on streaming files. I suggest you ask a new question (or edit this one) to remove references to regexes, since this is probably best solved using some other technique.

Answer (score 0):

You could concatenate each individual line into a 'buffer' string, and clean it out when the regex matches.

Ex:

```
buffer = line1line1line1line1\nline2line2line2line2
         | - - - - Regex Match - - - - - |
buffer = line2line2
```

String concatenation can be slow, especially with large strings, see: https://waymoot.org/home/python_string/